# puck: command not found

Tags: hockeyapp, xcode-server

I am uploading ipa from post trigger of Xcode Server to HockeyApp. I used puck command

puck -force=true -submit=auto -api_token=$TOKEN -app_id=$ID "$XCS_ARCHIVE"

This command works fine on terminal but It shows error 'puck: command not found' when run in post script. 
xcode server version : 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Xcode server is a separate device, please ensure that the puck client is also installed there.

The "command not found" error indicates two things:

- That you are not running it from a directory which includes the command
- The computer's `PATH` environment variable does not include the path to that directory

Full path to puck: `/usr/local/bin/puck`

Comment: sorry, but it's not full answer. Main problem of the puck - is installing on mac. If puck not installed what actions i have to do to resolve it?

Comment: This question seems to have what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158344/cant-install-helper-puck-from-hockeyapp-for-mac