# Can't install Helper, "Puck", from HockeyApp for Mac

Tags: macos, installation, macos-high-sierra, hockeyapp

Using High Sierra on a Mac, I am unable to install Puck from *HockeyApp for Mac* (version 2.0.21) with the [provided instructions](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-upload-to-hockeyapp-from-mac-os-x#installation).

When I choose "Install" from the "Preferences -> General" tab, the button turns gray, or disabled, I am prompted for my account's password and then... nothing. Puck is not installed in the **/usr/local/bin** directory as is suggested.

- My user account is an admin account.
- I am using the correct password.
- I have ownership and full write permissions to **/usr/local/bin**.
- I have both checked for updates and reinstalled *HockeyApp for Mac*

When I quit the *HockeyApp for Mac* app, and then return to it, the "Install" button is no longer disabled, but it is still offering me the ability to install Puck. It just never does.

Answer (score 6):

I finally resolved by uninstalling HockeyApp and re-installing using a different approach. Rather than downloading the installation program from the HockeyApp [website](https://hockeyapp.net/releases/mac/), I chose to install the application using homebrew. 
Assuming you have Homebrew and Homebrew-Cask installed, from the command line, use this:

```
brew cask install hockey
```

I don't know why it didn't work before. Perhaps it was my lack of understanding wrt Macs and installing software properly, but Homebrew did the trick. I was then able to install the "Helper" app of "Puck" onto my machine.

If you don't have Homebrew, or Homebrew-Cask installed, you may try the following. From the terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask 2> /dev/null
brew cask install hockey
```